# HIVE - Passing integer parameter

Tags: hive

### **Goal**:

Pass integer to hive scripts to retrieve certain element of an array

### **Error message**:

FAILED: SemanticException 30:32 Not proper type for index of ARRAY. Currently, only integer type is supported. Error encountered near token ''4''

### **Code**:

...
GROUP BY COALESCE(genre_id_array['${hiveconf:genre_x}'], '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.. GROUP BY COALESCE(genre_id_array[${hiveconf:genre_x}], '')
```

---

variables in Hive are nothing more than a text replacement mechanism.
If for example genre_x=123 than your original code after the variables expansion would look like:

```
... GROUP BY COALESCE(genre_id_array['123'], '')
```

As the error message stated, only integers (`123`) are currently supported as array indexes and not a strings (`'123'`).